# Ubuntu @myLaptop will boot only when failsafe graphics mode selected(several errors)

Tags: 11.04, boot-failure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“You do not appear to be using the nvidia x server”(screenshot included)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61792/you-do-not-appear-to-be-using-the-nvidia-x-serverscreenshot-included)

Suddenly cannot boot into Ubuntu.
I am running ubuntu 11.04 at my asus laptop.

Laptop specs:

- CPU: i5-2410M @ 2,3GHz
- RAM: 4GB
- GPU: nvidia gforce GT 520M / (also the cpu has a graphics processor)

I get these errors when I am trying to boot normally:

1. http://tinypic.com/r/mrdvt/7
2. http://tinypic.com/r/2ccvtci/7
3. http://tinypic.com/r/2uz9p9j/7
4. http://tinypic.com/r/242v0j8/7
5. http://tinypic.com/r/rab81z/7

I can only boot at ubuntu using the recovery and the failsafe graphic option..

Using lspci | grep VGA at the terminal, I get this:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation Device 1050 (rev a1)
```

What is wrong?
What should I do?

Comment: You are encouraged to post your solution as an answer (instead of putting it in your question) so we can mark the issue as solved, thanks!

Comment: Just tried to anwser my question but I have a limitation doing so due to my reputation. I have to wait 6 hours to self-anwser.

Comment: Ah cool, ok, I guess we'll just wait.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by xorg config file, see here:
["You do not appear to be using the nvidia x server"(screenshot included)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61792/you-do-not-appear-to-be-using-the-nvidia-x-serverscreenshot-included)

Sorry for the inconvenience.