# "You do not appear to be using the nvidia x server"(screenshot included)

Tags: xorg, nvidia, nvidia-optimus

I am running ubuntu 11.04 at my asus laptop.

Laptop specs:

```
CPU: i5-2410M @ 2,3GHz
RAM: 4GB
GPU: nvidia gforce GT 520M / (also the cpu has a bult-in graphics processor)
```

I am getting this error when I am trying to access the X server settings:

[image: screenshot]

Also, there is no xconfig file in the etc/x11 directory. Only the "xorg.cong.backup".
I've tried sudo startx and I got this:

```
Fatal server error:
Server is already active for display 0
    If this server is no longer running, remove /tmp/.X0-lock
    and start again.


Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 

 ddxSigGiveUp: Closing log
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 7 requests (7 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```

What is wrong?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I couldn't help but notice that it looks like you are using Unity 2D. I'm thinking you not only can't access your X settings, but you're not able to run 3D as well.

Comment: what graphics driver are you using? there is a beta and a "safe" version! (properity driver)

Comment: With this command "dpkg -l | grep nvidia"
 I got this: ii  nvidia-common                         0.2.30                                     Find obsolete NVIDIA drivers
ii  nvidia-current                        270.41.06-0ubuntu1                         NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU library
ii  nvidia-settings                       270.29-0ubuntu1                            Tool of configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The GT 520M is a nVidia Optimus laptop which is unsupported in Ubuntu. There are ways to get program to run on the nvidia card though which is described in [Is a NVIDIA GeForce with Optimus Technology supported by Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/36930/6969#36936)

After installing Bumblebee, you are able to run nvidia-settings using:

```
optirun nvidia-settings -c :8
```

Do not just run `nvidia-xconfig`, it'll create the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` configuration file which breaks compositing and such because the driver does not support the nvidia card out-of-the-box. If you've already ran that command, remove the file:

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
I have done all the four steps you have mentioned in the other question. You have written "If you'd like to run a program on the nvidia card now, use the optirun program". 1) So now every program is running on the built-in graphics processor of the CPU?
2) Is this built-in gpu handling the windows effects as well?
3) Which programmes should I run on the nvidia card?
4) To get this right, the whole problem is due to the optimus technology on my nvidia gt 520m?
5) I tried running this: nvidia-settings -c :8 and got this: ERROR: Cannot open display ':8'.

Comment: 1) A program is rendered on the nvidia card but the result is displayed using the intel card 2) No, the desktop runs on the intel card. You can try to run the whole session using optirun by editing the session file in `/usr/share/xsessions`, but this may not be that stable since not all GL features are (correctly) implemented. 3) Programs which heavily rely on graphics like internet browsers (Firefox, Chromium) and media players (VLC). Keep in mind that the nvidia card uses more power, so only use it if really needed 4) Correct. 5) The Bumblebee X server was not started. Run it with `optirun`.

Comment: 1)So now, firefox runs on the intel card, right?
2)You mean that I have to run every program I want using this command "optirun program &"? Which means that if I want to open a movie I will firstly have to open vlc via that command and then open the video file? :S Isn't there any way to choose which programmes will run on the nvidia card?
3)About the 5th question and the answer you provided.How should I start the bumblebee x server?Which command? This:
    optirun bumblebee -d
?
Sorry I'm not an experienced user..

Comment: 1) Correct 2) Indeed. You can edit the desktop files to make it run in optirun, which is what `bumblebee-ui` does. Unfortunately, it is not compatible yet with recent Bumblebee releases 3) It is started on boot time and after installation of Bumblebee. You'll be given instructions on using `optirun` when it's not started.

Comment: When running additional drivers I get this: http://tinypic.com/r/10d787b/7. 1)The nvidia driver is not activated because of the bumblebee? 2)Isn't there any workaround to avoid this related to the execution of applications problem? And generally a workaround to avoid this incompatibility (without the bumblebee)? Something like that maybe: http://blog.musicvm.com/solved-you-do-not-appear-be-using-nvidia-x-driver-linux-ubuntu ?
Isn't nvidia going to compensate for this problem?I really don't want to go through the whole terminal>running program>opening file procedure?
Thank you for your replies.

Comment: 1) It could mean that the driver is not used by the current, active X server. 2) You indeed need to run a program explicitly with `optirun`. If you wish to avoid having to run `optirun` for each program, you may do something like `optirun bash` and then run programs from that shell. This is not the most user-friendly way, but we (the Bumblebee Project team) are working on it. The linked blog your posted is not going to help, it has nothing to do with conflicting nvidia drivers. Nvidia is [not going to support it](http://www.nvnews.net/vbulletin/showpost.php?p=2291824)

Comment: How can I make an optirun bash? In the case of VLC, if I want it always to run on the nvidia card, isn't there any way to add the optirun VLC & as a command everytime it is executed?

Comment: For VLC, try: `cp /usr/share/applications/vlc.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/vlc.desktop&&sed 's,^Exec=,&optirun ,' -i ~/.local/share/applications/vlc.desktop`. You may need to refresh your menu items, for KDE this is done by running `kbuildsycoca4`.

Comment: Thank you for the command.
I am trying to understand its "mechanics"
1)What is vlc.desktop ?
2)what's the ~/ ?
In general if it isn't too much imposition could you explain the command?

This command makes vlc automatically run on the nvidia card?

Comment: 1) Desktop files are used by Ubuntu to create application entries on the desktop or in the applications menu. It contains name, path to command, icon and much more. See also http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/. 2) `~` expands to your home directory which is typically `/home/yourusername`. The command copies the global desktop file to your local one and if that succeeds, it changes `Exec=` to `Exec=optirun ` (with trailing space) which makes it be run with `optirun`.

Comment: Dude I'm so happy. It is actually working now. I'm so so happy. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @Lekensteyn If I run `nvidia-settings` via `optirun` as indicated in this answer they are useless because they refer to virtual screen is that correct? If yes, how can one take profits from those advanced screen settings which `Nvidia X server settings` normally provides?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running in the terminal:

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

and then rebooting? That should take care of it all for you.

Comment: Tried that and got this:
WARNING: Unable to locate/open X configuration file.

New X configuration file written to '/etc/X11/xorg.conf'.

After that I rebooted and got this screen:
http://tinypic.com/r/mrdvt/7
I've managed to boot at ubuntu into failsafe graphics mode.
So this problem ( http://askubuntu.com/questions/61559/ubuntu-mylaptop-will-boot-only-when-failsafe-graphics-mode-selectedseveral-erro) is not solved.

Comment: I failed to notice that you are using an Optimus card and merely noticed that you never mentioned running the command I recommended you. Lekensteyn's answer is better suited than my own. Apologies.